# Custom PermissionEvaluator does not work when security configuration is put outside of service - in seperate jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

So I am trying to make common/utility jar which will store my spring security configuration and custom permission evaluator and some additional stuff. And then services which will need to have access to it will just add it to the project.
But for some reason it does not work properly, my configuration and beans are loaded correctly. But when I am trying access my example endpoint it does not go into my custom permission evaluator, which is strange. Because before moving this code outside of my webservice everything was correctly.

I am using Spring Boot 3+, and java 17.
And my code looks like following:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission('example')")
@GetMapping(path = "/", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<List<String>> getAll()
```

Security Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
//Tried both
@EnableMethodSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .csrf().disable()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodSecurityExpressionHandler customMethodSecurityExpressionHandler() {
        System.out.println("Creating customMethodSecurityExpressionHandler");

        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler =
                new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(customPermissionEvaluator());
        return expressionHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomPermissionEvaluator customPermissionEvaluator() {
        System.out.println("Creating customPermissionEvaluator");
        return new CustomPermissionEvaluator();
    }
}
```

And evaluator

```
public class CustomPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {

    public CustomPermissionEvaluator() {
        System.out.println("constructor CustomPermissionEvaluator");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication auth, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication auth, Serializable targetId, String targetType, Object permission) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Any idea where can be an issue?